# How do i implement a better search with PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, postgresql

I am searching for names in my PostgreSQL database using `ilike %name%`.

The problem is too many names get matched and my display environment is limited, so my search output is limited to 20. In essence I might just miss out on names which match the input string even more.

I store my name (First name, middle name, last name) in one column. Here is the search code snippet:

```
select l_name from leader_info where (l_name ilike $1 or l_name ilike $2 or l_name ilike $3)
```

I usually split any inputted string into 3. 
When I search a name like:

> Tom Wolf

I get matches like:

> Samuel Ortom, steve waltom, sam tommer

I would prefer getting only matches like:

> tom hanks, Wilfred tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way may be this.

(for example matches only words "tom" and "steve")

```
with t(col) as(
    select  'Samuel Ortom' union all
    select  'tom hanks' union all
    select  'Wilfred tom' union all
    select  'steve waltom' union all
    select  'A steven' union all
    select  'sam tommer'  
)

select * from t where 
to_tsvector(col) @@ to_tsquery('tom')
or
to_tsvector(col) @@ to_tsquery('steve');
```

or also can be: `... where to_tsvector(col) @@ to_tsquery('Tom | steve')`

This is postgres  [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-SEARCH) and it can be also optimized using indexes.

Comment: It works, but i need the search  to be case insensitive, i want tom and Tom to match the same result, thanks @OtoShavadze

Comment: @OnyemenamNdubuisi - You tested and this not matches "Tom" ?

Comment: My bad, works like a charm thanks @OtoShavadze, are there any speed issues, or any other pitfalls of using this query as against using ILIKE

Comment: You can use indexes for speed us search, follow link in my answer and see `Creating Indexes` section

Comment: Thanks @OtoShavadze  why did you edit your answer, the other one worked well

Comment: @OnyemenamNdubuis - Sorry, edited again, I just added another syntax (for searching multiple words with `OR` condition)

Comment: Have a look at the pg_trgm extension. It allows to have indexes for `ILIKE '%something%'` but also regular expression searches.